# period characters for current and parent directories in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, posix, freebsd

Are two following snippets equivalent?
(This code is from the line 36 in [one file of rc scripts of freebsd](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/etc/rc.d/cleanvar).)

```
[ ."$file" = .. -o ."$file" = ... ]
```

and

```
[ "$file" = . -o "$file" = .. ]
```

If so, why is the former used there?

Comment: Maybe at one point the shell didn't handle empty quoted variables properly, and the script was never updated when it finally did.

Comment: Indeed. That seems like a remnant fix like the usage of `x$var` you see in other places for unquoted variables causing `[` to throw errors when the variable was empty. I suppose it is possible there are `[` versions that had the same problem with quoted empty variables too.